# How can I rearrange UITabBarController items using the Storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard

Hi I have a UITabBarController in XCode 4.5 as the root controller with many tabs I need to change the order to.

The only thing that works for me is remove the relationships and add them again in the desired order that I want the tabbar items to appear.

Is there another way to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 171, accepted):

In the storyboard highlight the tab bar controller.

Make sure you are zoomed in enough and that a blue box is around the tab bar 
controller.

Then click on the tabs and drag them around to where you want them

Comment: Well this doesn't do it for me, I can't rearrange them by dragging and dropping. Has this changed in iOS 6?

Comment: @Bazze make sure you are on the tab bar controller and not a view controller for 1 of the tabs

Comment: @MobileMon I was in the tab bar controller, but it seems like it was some kind of temporary bug. I restarted XCode and now it works just fine.

Comment: I just faced the same thing and yes it is a bug but you don't need to restart Xcode, just click on any .h or .m file then click back on the story board it should work normally.

Comment: May sound stupid but clicking the tab item won't highlight it until you try to drag it.

Comment: This answer worked perfectly for me in Xcode 12.0, thanks.

Answer (score 25):

I solved this by right-clicking on the storyboard -> open as source code, and then rearranged the "segue" xml-blocks in the order I wanted them to be.

Comment: Shame on Apple that still on Xcode 8.2.1 we still need to open Storyboard as source code and move segues to solve this.

Comment: This worked for me using Xamarin in Visual Studio! Had to close the Storyboard, but opening the file in a text editor and finding what my TabBarController was named, you can easily rearrange based on the order they're in. Save it, re-open in Visual Stuido, worked great! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

xcode 4.5, drag and drop failed.  as suggested by another, close xcode and restart xcode.  after this drag and drop of tabBarItems worked perfectly to rearrange order.

Answer (score 5):

I could not drag and tabs around while i had the tab bar controller as root view of navigation controller.  I had to delete the navigation controller and restart xcode (4.5.2)

Answer (score 3):

Some of the suggestions above worked for me sometimes, but not always. Even rebooting the Mac did not help.
The only way I found that works always is deleting all segues from the tab bar controller to its child view controllers, and reconnecting them in the right order.

Answer (score 3):

When working with Xamarin iOS Designer, I open the .storyboard file in a text editor and locate the `<tabBarController ...>` node. Then I rearrange the order of the segues in the `<connections>` section:

```
<connections>
    <segue destination="274" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="286"/>
    <segue id="943" destination="910" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers"/>
    <segue destination="147" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="159"/>
</connections>
```

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Make sure you are zoomed in enough and that a blue box is around the tab bar controller.

**2)** Then click on the tabs and drag them around to where you want them.

**3)** if it is not working , just click on any .h or .m file and then go to storyboard file and try.

**4)** even though it is not working , just restart xcod and try it.

Comment: there may be some other issue , did u checked that it is "Zoomed out" enough ?

Comment: It does not work. XCode 4.5.2. Very-very annoying bug, drives me crazy

Answer (score 1):

Click and drag worked for me with Xcode 6.2 with the correct zoom level.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using Xcode 5 and above you should just drag and drop them:

[image]