# Rearrange Tab Bar items not working as expected

Tags: xcode, ios6, storyboard, tabbarcontroller

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796208/how-can-i-rearrange-uitabbarcontroller-items-using-the-storyboard), I have so far been unable to rearrange tab bar items in my iPad app.

I have zoomed in as far as I can go and double-clicked the tab bar controller so that it is highlighted in the Document Outline inspector.

I then try to click-drag individual items left or right but nothing happens, i.e. I'm unable to select them.

Following the comments on the other question, I've tried clicking on another .h or .m file, then switching back to the Storyboard. I've also tried closing x-code and restarting but neither made any difference.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I took the brute force approach of deleting the segues then reconnecting in the preferred order.

Not particularly elegant but it did the job.